# Problema con separar una URL en java

Tags: java, array, eclipse, url

Intento separar una URL en 3 partes y guardarlo todo en un Array. Sé que no estoy usando el regex, me gustaria usarlo.

Siendo esta la URL:

http://www.devbg.org/forum/index.php

Daría esto:

resultado[0]: "http"

resultado[1]: "www.devbg.org"

resultado[2]: "/forum/index.php"

Este es el código con el que lo he estado intentando:

**Main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String URL = "http://www.devbg.org/forum/index.php";
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(separarURL(URL));
        }
    }
```

**Método:**

```
public static String[] separarURL(String URL) {
        String regex = "^(?:([^:]*):(?://)?)?([^/]*)(/.*)?";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher concordance = pattern.matcher(URL);
        String protocolo = "";
        String dominio = "";
        String ruta = "";
        
        if (concordance.find()) {
            protocolo = concordance.group(1);
            dominio = concordance.group(2);
            ruta = concordance.group(3);
        }
        
        String[] URLseparada = {protocolo, dominio, ruta};
        return URLseparada;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parece que tu error esta en el modo de imprimir el array que genera  tu método,ya que estas usando `print` el cual cual concatena todos los datos que están en el array en vez de ello puedes hacer uso de `println` el cual imprime con salto de linea,lo otro es hacer uso del tamaño del arreglo generado no del parámetro del metodo `main`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String URL = "http://www.devbg.org/forum/index.php";

        for (int i = 0; i < separarURL(URL).length; i++) {
            System.out.println(separarURL(URL)[i]);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu método `separarURL()` es correcto ya que obtiene un arreglo de valores a partir de la url, por lo tanto debes envíar la url como parámetro, obtendrás un array de elementos y si deseas imprimirlos puedes iterar el array que contiene los valores:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String URL = "http://www.devbg.org/forum/index.php";
 
    //Obtiene los segmentos de la url en un array
    String[] segmentosUrl = separarURL(URL);

    //Itera el array para obtener los valores almacenados.
    for (int i = 0; i < segmentosUrl.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("resultado["+i+"] " + segmentosUrl[i]);
    }
}
```

Salida:

```
resultado[0] http
resultado[1] www.devbg.org
resultado[2] /forum/index.php
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias. Ya me funciona.