# Dividir un String en partes

Tags: java, string, url

Hol@, saludos, estoy practicando y me he quedado piado en un ejercicio que dice:

Realiza un programa que pida una dirección web, del estilo de: http://www.google.com, la
analice y muestre esto en pantalla:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Introduzcame una URL: ");
    String url = sc.nextLine();
    int posicion = url.indexOf(":");
    String protocolo = url.substring(0, posicion);
    int posicion2 = url.indexOf(1, posicion);
    System.out.println(posicion2);// ya no se como seguir si podían echarme una mano, gracias..!
```

Comment: ¿Eso es java? Si es así deberías añadir la etiqueta. Además obtendrías más ayuda.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema con separar una URL en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/512295/problema-con-separar-una-url-en-java)

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que debe mostrar? ¿Entiendes lo que has escrito hasta ahora? A partir de eso puedes terminar tu ejercicio.